# Vim, delete whitespace between 2 lines

Tags: vim

given the following:

```
{
    int a = 123;
    int b = 456;
}
```

i want to change it to:

```
{
    int a = 123;int b = 456;
}
```

if i was using a regular text editor, i would go to the 2nd line, then <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>,<kbd>Delete</kbd>

what's vim way of doing this?  it should work with any amount of whitespace between line 1 and line 2.

Comment: side note: depending on the editor you're (now not) using, you can just do `Home,Ctrl+Backspace` on the second line or `End,Ctrl+Delete` on the first

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the `J` command. It joins two lines (applied on the first one).
If you want to join two lines, separated by several empty lines easily, you can also select the lines between the two in visual mode (`V`) and then apply `J`.

However, that command inserts one space between joined lines ([in most cases...](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#J)).

For your requirements, you can use the variant `gJ` which does not insert (or remove) any space between the lines.

Comment: that works perfectly!  thanks.  i meant 'whitespaces' as in like multiple spaces and/or tabs, like when code is deeply nested.  but 'J' works there too.

Comment: I've found that `gJ` doesn't modify the whitespace, it just removes the newline and you're left with all of the indent whitespace between the two parts of the new line.  I've wished on occasion for a version of `J` that removed all intervening whitespace but not enough to actually write one.  :)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang yes that's possible, I've never used it really. I usually select lines with `V` to delete with `d` and after that I join lines if needed.

Comment: why didn't I know this like 10 years ago. I never joined lines just because it was too much of a hassle.